# Is it possible for Arduino firmware to recognise only one computer?

Tags: arduino-uno, firmware

Is it possible to adjust the Arduino firmware to recognise only one PC computer? On other computers it would show driver not recognised or driver not found.

E.g.: My computer should see the Arduino normally, and it should not work if I connect the same arduino to other computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

However, it is possible to place unusual and/or secret requirements on the computer's drivers or application software - however those software components could be present on multiple computers unless you also take measures to node lock them.

- You could customize the USB VID/PID and descriptors, causing the device not to be recognized by a usual driver
- You could alter the behavior of the USB interface (or bootloader and sketch) to require unusual operations - either obscure, or even secret to the level of unique-per-unit cryptography
- Or most simply, you could just use a board without a USB interface and bring your own.  Especially if you lock the flash, there's not a whole lot others can do except entirely erase your work and be left with an unusually expensive ATmega evaluation board.

Do note also that most operating systems make it possible to easily intercept the raw USB traffic going to/from devices, so someone who can see it in operation can learn a lot about how it is working.

If you want to play games with odd USB implementations, you'll probably do better with a direct USB board like a Leonardo - and you will certainly want to have an ISP setup to recover it, as your efforts will no doubt break it many times before you get something on there which works as intended.

Comment: Thanks for nice answer. I will try first solution, if not suceed, i will use simplest solution - third.